# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get after update attempt

Tags: wp-update-post, fatal-error, deactivated-plugin

I received the following error after attempting to update my WordPress to the latest version **Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_cache_get() in /home/fairmftt/public_html/wp-includes/option.php on line 1117**

After going through the support forum **I deactivated my plugins but this made the problem worse** - I now get that error if I go directly to that website. Also, when I log into WordPress (not the dashboard) I can't do anything to the page including updating the error. All the plugins have disappeared, and I can't seem to find anyone else with a similar problem.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you able to reinstall WordPress manually (via ftp or ssh)?

Answer (score 0):

I think W3 Total Cache or any Cache related plugin is still activate in your site.

**Try to de-active all plugins manually.**

---

Using **Database**

Open Phpmyadmin Database of the website.

1. In the table wp_options, under the option_name column (field) find the `active_plugins` row.
2. Change the option_value field to: a:0:{}

---

Using **FTP** or **SSH**

In case you don't have access to cPanel you can do this through FTP.

1. Login in FTP and open to `wp-content`
2. rename `plugins` folder to `plugins_deactive`.

This both tricks will disable all plugins.

> *After testing, Don't forget to rename plugin's folder name to `plugins`.*

*If still not works, Then it can be theme issue.*

Hope this help!